# rails 4 asset pipeline-- javascript not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to add a gallery js ([S3Slider](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/)) to my rails 4 project. According to most of the docs, this should be added to the `vendor/assets/javascripts/` directory. 
According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization, I can add the javascript file to to `vendor/assets/javascripts/s3slider/s3slider.js` and reference it from the `application.js` file like this:

```
//= require s3slider
```

The specific example given in the Rails docs is

```
vendor/assets/somepackage/phonebox.js
```

would be referenced by

```
//= require phonebox
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
couldn't find file 's3slider'
(in /home/julio/rails_projects/demo_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)
```

I stopped the rails server and restarted it, but the error persists. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: moving the s3slider.js file out of the s3slider directory enabled rails to find it. However, still unclear why the example in the official docs says you can use directory structures like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have the `s3slider.js` file inside a folder with the same name you have to:

```
//= require s3slider/s3slider
```

or add a directive to the folder:

```
//= require_tree s3slider
```

The asset pipeline is searching for a file `s3slider` directly in `javascripts` folder. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: @cortex-- thanks. So it's simply a mistake in the rails docs, and the `phonebox` directive should really be `//= require somepackage/phonebox` ?

Comment: There is not a mistake. In the case of the Rails docs `somepackage` is `javascripts` for example. And is added to `config.assets.paths` in `application.rb`. If works for you, consider marking the answer as accepted ;)